# Wrong usage of repeatOnLifecycle from MainActivity.onStart

Tags: android, kotlin-flow

Whenever we call repeatOnLifecycle suspend function to collect from a flow. Calling from onStart or onResume gives the error

> Wrong usage of repeatOnLifecycle from MainActivity.onStart or MainActivity.onResume

Answer (score 3):

Note: repeatOnLifecycle API available in the lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0 library or later.

> right way to call repeatOnLifecycle is from onCreate of Activity or
> from onViewCreated in Fragment.

more here -> https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/a-safer-way-to-collect-flows-from-android-uis-23080b1f8bda